# Passing indexPath of the tableView cell to the another controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, segue

I want to pass the `select row` as `indexPath`  to the another controller. for that i have write following code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();

    return cell
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var secondController: SecondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController
    secondController.rowIndex.text = indexPath
}
```

But my indexPath is nil. Why?

Comment: where is the didselectrowatindexpath ?

Comment: you can not pass indexPath to nsstring

Comment: Actually you are declared "indexPath" as a local variable and its scope is within its method. also you have written in "cellFOrRowAtIndexPath", this method is call number of times as per number of cell display on screen. so better is that, you should override "didselectrowatindexpath" and assign selected indexPath as global variable.

Answer (score 2):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath  , this is wrong:

```
let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();
```

For each row you are saving the selected row in a variable which will be destroyed after cellForRowAtIndexPath finishes, because it is not retained by any object.

You just need this in prepareForSegue

```
var secondController: SecondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController
if let selectedIndexPath =  tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();
    secondController.rowIndex= selectedIndexPath.row
```

Haven't tested, but think this will work. Hope it helps.

Comment: In Javier's suggestion you may need to use secondController.rowIndex.text = "/(selectedIndexPath)" to cast to text or declare rowIndex in secondController as NSIndexPath

Comment: one question about `didselectrowatindexpath`. Must I use it instead of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or?

Comment: Yes, if this doesnt work probably is because you should  mark the cell  as selected in 'didselectrowatindexpath'   let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell;
currentCell.selected = true

Comment: Under the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I create a func `didselectrowatindexpath` with the `let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();
        println(indexPath)` but it crashes

Comment: because indexPathForSelectedRow() is an optional, you should check if it contains any value before accessing itself.You can check it doing what I wroted above: if let selectedIndexPath =  tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();

Answer (score 0):

To satisfied your requirement do the following things.

Step 1 : Declare globle variable(that scope is within class).

like `var selectedIndexForRow:Int? = nil`

`var selectedIndexForSection:Int? = nil`

Step 2 : Override `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

selectedIndexForRow = indexPath.row;
selectedIndexForSection = indexPath.section;


}
```

Step 3: Pass `selectedIndexForRow` and `selectedIndexForSection` variables to another controller

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
var secondController: SecondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController
secondController.row= selectedIndexForRow
secondController.section= selectedIndexForSection
}
```

Comment: NSIndexPath `Use of undeclarated type NSIndexPath`

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade, for now you can used as `var selectedIndex:Int? = nil` for  storeing row only if you want to store section as well then create another variable and followed same process. i have updating my answer. please check that.

Comment: Or you need change syntax formatting of declaring global variable of `NSIndexPath` like `var selectedIndex: NSIndexPath?`

Answer (score 0):

The `sender` here in `prepareForSegue` is the `UITableViewCell` that you have selected.

Simply typecast it to `UITableViewCell` and then call `indexPathForCell` on your `tableView`. That will return you the `indexPath` of the selected cell. No need for additional variables, global or otherwise.

I'm sorry I cannot post any Swift code. I am proficient in Obj-c but I don't know Swift yet.

Sample code for Obj-C is as follows. I hope you'll write the Swift equivalent yourself, or somebody here will edit it in.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    UITableViewCell* cell = (UITableViewCell*)sender;

    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    //Use indexPath as you intend to
}
```